# Using std::cout with Visual Studio Test feature

Tags: c++, view, console, cout

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and have created a C++ Test project using their test adapter for Google Test. I would like to write some output to stdout from the test and view it after the test run. It does not appear in the output window. Any ideas on how to view stdout or console output from a test within Visual Studio test facilities?

Answer (score -1):

The Visual Studio seems to have separate debug output window. To that window we can write like `OutputDebugStringA("Bla bla blah.");` It has nothing to do with `stdout` AFAIK.

Comment: I did mean debug output window inside of visual studio IDE where you supposedly run the tests.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do see it in the debug window as you said. I wonder if there is also a way to do it when not debugging it. It would be great if I could just std::cout << "something" << std::endl; and see it even when running release and not running in debug.

Comment: You mean from GUI application without visual studio? Then you can make a console window as part of your application.  Basic demos of concept are easy to find: https://gist.github.com/kingseva/a918ec66079a9475f19642ec31276a21 It is more work, but have fun.